# when I do ' sudo apt-get install -f ',I met error as follows

Tags: 14.04, openssh

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-client_1%3a6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb
     /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when I do `sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10`,I met another error :

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ssh : Depends: openssh-server (>= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Do  `sudo apt autoclean` & `sudo apt autoremove` and then try `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: 'supermicro@supermicro04:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo apt autoclean
E: Invalid operation autoclean
supermicro@supermicro04:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo apt autoremove
E: Invalid operation autoremove'

Comment: 「supermicro@supermicro04:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ssh : Depends: openssh-client (>= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10)
       Depends: openssh-server (>= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.」

Comment: And if you do `sudo apt clean`?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/  
sudo rm openssh-client_1%3a6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb openssh-server_1%3a6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb  
sudo apt update     
sudo apt install openssh-client
```

Alternatively you can replace the command `sudo apt install openssh-client` with `sudo apt install ssh` . `ssh` is a metapackage that installs both secure shell client and server.

Answer (score 0):

First get root:

```
sudo su
```

Next do:

```
 lsattr /usr/bin/ssh
```

Remove the ia:

```
chattr -i /usr/bin/ssh 
chattr -a /usr/bin/ssh
```

Fix the dependencies

```
apt-get -f install
```

Instal Openssh-client

```
apt-get install openssh-client
```

Next do

```
lsattr /usr/sbin/sshd
```

remove ia:

```
chattr -i /usr/sbin/sshd 
chattr -a /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Update aptitude

```
apt-get update
```

Instal Openssh-client

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: Amazing！I have solved this bug  according to  your instruction.sThank you very  much!